# Validation rule on lead object

Tags: validation-rule, leads

Requirement:
When New Lead is created with Course Type as online, phone no cannot be blank

The below validation rule which i tried.

```
AND(
ISNEW(ISPICKVAL(CourseType__c,'online'))),
ISNULL(Phone)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND( ISNEW(),ISPICKVAL(CourseType__c,'online'),ISBLANK(Phone))
```

Answer (score 2):

The ISNEW function does not take any parameters.

```
AND(
    ISNEW(),
    ISPICKVAL(CourseType__c, 'online'),
    ISNULL(Phone)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one also works well.

Please use this formula:

`IF(ISNEW() && Phone==null && ISPICKVAL(CourseType__c ,'online'),true, false)`

As Adrian is saying we also need to add the ISNEW() in the formula to target new records only..so, I added the ISNEW() in the formula and it works fine.

Comment: You're not checking if it's a new record. You can also always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`.

Comment: You right Adrian, the ISNEW() needs to be part of the formula as well.. I updated my answer.

Comment: It's still redundant.